# Dynamics CRM 2015 Online: SubGrid's control.SetParameter method is not available

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm trying to populate a subgrid with fetchXml results in CRM 2015 online. One issue in the beginning was that `document.getElementById("leadUmbrellaGrid");` returns null

```
function filterSubGrid() {

    var leadwithSameNameGrid = Xrm.Page.getControl("leadUmbrellaGrid").getGrid();//HAVE TRIED window.parent.document.getElementById("leadUmbrellaGrid"); //grid to filter
    var currentleadId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();;
    if (leadwithSameNameGrid == null) {

        setTimeout('filterSubGrid()', 500);
        return;
    }
    //fetch xml code 
    var fetchXml = "<fetchxml goes here>";


    leadwithSameNameGrid.control.SetParameter("fetchXml", fetchXml); //set the fetch xml to the sub grid   
    leadwithSameNameGrid.control.refresh(); //refresh the sub grid using the new fetch xml

}
```

I have gone through [this](http://musingsofasoftwareenthusiast.blogspot.se/2015/08/dynamics-crm-2015-update-1-applying.html) and [this](https://joshimandarblog.wordpress.com/2015/02/04/crm-2015-applying-custom-fetchxml-to-a-subgrid-using-javascript/#comments)

I tried `window.parent.document.getElementById` as well but in both cases, the `.control` is null or undefined and end up with:

**TypeError: Unable to get property 'SetParameter' of undefined or null reference**

Would appreciate your help/tips.
Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the solution:

1. We need to use `window.parent.document.getElementById`
2. Wait for the `control` to load in the DOM.

So the code would look like this:

```
function filterSubGrid() 
{

    var leadwithSameNameGrid = window.parent.document.getElementById("leadUmbrellaGrid");
    var currentleadId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();;
    if (leadwithSameNameGrid == null) 
    {
        setTimeout(filterSubGrid, 500);
        return;
    }

    //fetch xml code 
    var fetchXml = "<fetchxml goes here>";
    if (leadwithSameNameGrid.control != null) 
    {
        leadwithSameNameGrid.control.SetParameter("fetchXml", fetchXml); //set the fetch xml to the sub grid   
        leadwithSameNameGrid.control.refresh(); //refresh the sub grid using the new fetch xml
    } 
    else 
    {
        setTimeout(filterSubGrid, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this line 'if (relatedProjectsSubGrid.control != null) {' where does relatedProjectsSubGrid come from?

Comment: Could you please use leadwithSameNameGrid.control instead of relatedProjectsSubGrid.control in the if condition and let me know if that works?

Answer (score 1):

```
function filterSubGrid() {

        var leadwithSameNameGrid = window.parent.document.getElementById("leadUmbrellaGrid");
        var currentleadId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();;
        if (leadwithSameNameGrid == null) {

            setTimeout('filterSubGrid()', 500);
            return;
        }
        //fetch xml code 
        var fetchXml = "<fetchxml goes here>";
        if (relatedProjectsSubGrid.control != null) {
        leadwithSameNameGrid.control.SetParameter("fetchXml", fetchXml); //set the fetch xml to the sub grid   
        leadwithSameNameGrid.control.refresh(); //refresh the sub grid using the new fetch xml
          } else {
        setTimeout('filterSubGrid()', 500);
        }

    }
```

Ive tried this one but didn't quite get where did you get the "relatedProjectsSubGrid.control", also is this still working for CRM 7.1?
Thanks