# SetParameter("fetchXml", FetchXml) doesn't support in crm 2016 online

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have this code:

```
function FilterCasesSubgrid() {
    //var CasesSubgrid = Xrm.Page.getControl("contact").getGrid();
    var CasesSubgrid = window.parent.document.getElementById("contact");

    if(CasesSubgrid==null){ 
    setTimeout(function () { FilterCasesSubgrid(); }, 2000); //if the grid hasn’t loaded run this again when it has 
    return;
    }
    var fetchXml ="<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>"+
    "<entity name='contact'>"+
    "<attribute name='fullname' />"+
    "<filter type='and'>"+
    "<condition attribute='fullname' operator='eq' value='s%' />"+
    "</filter>"+
    "</entity>"+
    "</fetch>";
    //Here i set the fetchxml directly to subgrid
    CasesSubgrid.control.SetParameter("fetchXml", fetchXml); //set the fetch xml to the sub grid 
    CasesSubgrid.control.Refresh(); //refresh the sub grid using the new fetch xml 
}
```

ERROR :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'SetParameter' of undefined at
>   FilterCasesSubgrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code isnt supported so you shouldnt expect it to work. Using any function which directly accesses the DOM (i.e; `window.parent.document.getElementById`) or uses function not defined within the [MSDN SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932126.aspx) is unsupported and should be avoided.

However, given that all you seem to be doing is adding a filter, there are supported methods for doing this by setting an existing FetchXML query:

```
var myView = {
    entityType: 1039, // SavedQuery
    id:"{3A282DA1-5D90-E011-95AE-00155D9CFA02}", 
    name: "My Custom View"
}

//Set the view using ContactsIFollow
Xrm.Page.getControl("Contacts").getViewSelector().setCurrentView(myView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wait for the element **AND** the control property (CasesSubgrid.control).

This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564310/dynamics-crm-2015-online-subgrids-control-setparameter-method-is-not-available)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

- We need to use **window.parent.document.getElementById**
- Wait for the control to load in the DOM.

So the code would look like this:

```js
function FilterCasesSubgrid() 
{
    //var CasesSubgrid = Xrm.Page.getControl("contact").getGrid();
    var CasesSubgrid =   window.parent.document.getElementById("contact");

    if(CasesSubgrid==null)
    { 
    setTimeout(function () { FilterCasesSubgrid(); }, 2000); //if the grid hasn’t loaded run this again when it has 
    return;
    }
    var fetchXml ="<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>"+
    "<entity name='contact'>"+
    "<attribute name='fullname' />"+
    "<filter type='and'>"+
    "<condition attribute='fullname' operator='eq' value='s%' />"+
    "</filter>"+
    "</entity>"+
    "</fetch>";
    //Here i set the fetchxml directly to subgrid
  if(CasesSubgrid.control != null)
    {
    CasesSubgrid.control.SetParameter("fetchXml", fetchXml); //set the fetch xml to the sub grid 
    CasesSubgrid.control.Refresh(); //refresh the sub grid using the new fetch xml 
      }
  else
    {
       setTimeout(CasesSubgrid, 500);
      }
}
```

Comment: I have two custom entity N:N relation.